# Python: Looking for things in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def
    for i in play.inventory:
        if "Sword" in i and "[S]lash" not in abilities:
            abilities.append("[S]lash")
        elif "Bow" in i and "[F]ire" not in abilities:
            abilities.append("[F]ire")
        elif "Fists" in i and "[P]unch" not in abilities:
            abilities.append("[P]unch")
        elif "Legs" in i and "[K]ick" not in abilities: 
            abilities.append("[K]ick ")
        return abilities
```

So currently I have this code from a separate question of mine but when using it most of it goes smoothly except it only recognizes "Fists" (The list is ['Fists','Legs']) I haven't tried if Sword triggers it yet, but I'd like this fixed first, The expected outcome should be:

```
abilities = ["[K]ick","[P]unch"]
```

In which then I print it out using:

```
 for a in aca:
    print(a)
```

Where aca is abilities.

Currently it outcomes this:

```
for a in aca:
    print(a)
>>[P]unch
```

Using PyCharm CE, Python 3.5.2

Due to request:
play.inventory is an object of a class (I think?) code for it:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.inventory = []

play = Player()
```

Comment: you forgot to post _at least_ what "play.inventory" is...

Comment: Done. Sorry about that

Comment: With `play.inventory` being an empty list, `abilities` should come out as an empty list too. Please post a  minimal complete verifiable example :  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You return after 1st iteration, so the rest of the loop never runs. Is `inventory` a list of strings? Ditch the for-loop and do the `in` checks on it directly. Now you're testing if the strings contain "Sword" etc., one at a time. If on the other hand you mean to have "Sword Legs" as an item in the future, keep the loop (just fix the return statements indentation).

Comment: @IljaEverilä well spotted, I missed that one...

Comment: play.inventory is not an empty list, I was just presenting some code. To clear up confusion it actually has two items "Legs" and "Fists. Also can you be a little bit more clear on your answer @lljaEverila? Sorry I just don't know how to read codespeak

Comment: The for-loop ends in a return statement. That exits the function right away, never continuing the loop after 1st item. I suspect that you've just wrong indentation, i.e. you meant to return after the loop has run.

Comment: This is a function so I thought I needed to add a return if I needed the abilities ever again?

Comment: what @Ilja\ Everilä  is saying is you need to move ``return`` statement outside of ``for`` loop

Comment: It is just a bit too much to the right. As it is now it is a part of the for-loop's body. Move it 1 indentation level to the left, so it is evaluated after the loop, not as part of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the elif and just use if, also a **set** will help you a lot here.

```
    abilities = set(abilities) #this will make each item appear only once...
    if "Sword" in play.inventory:
        abilities.add("[S]lash")
    if "Bow" in play.inventory:
        abilities.add("[F]ire")
    if "Fists" in play.inventory:
        abilities.add("[P]unch")
    if "Legs" in play.inventory:
        abilities.add("[K]ick ")
    return list(abilities)
```

you can also do it in a single loop

```
    i2a = {"Sword": "[S]lash",
           "Bow": "[F]ire",
           "Fists": "[P]unch",
           "Legs": "[K]ick"}
    for i, a in i2a.items():
        if i in play.inventory:
           abilities.append(a)
    return list(set(abilities)) #another way to remove duplicates...
```